# How to DELETE Windows 10 from a Dell XPS-15z laptop

Tags: windows-10

Google, Duck Duck Go, the major search engines, are happy to provide thousands of
links to sites which *pretend* to be about deleting Windows but are false, misleading
and only have info on deleting some version or other of Windows and reinstalling
whatever the OEM / Windows had been.

Please help!

Expunge.  Purge.  Delete.  Nuke from space.  RID the laptop of Windows, 100%.
Why do search engines not understand those terms.  *Because reasons* I guess, but
it seems it should be doable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. At the Dell splash screen press F2 to enter UEFI firmware settings (aka BIOS Setup).
2. Once in the UEFI firmware settings you should be able to select "Wipe on Next Boot" from the Maintenance->Data Wipe option to invoke data wipe for all internal drives after the reboot.

If you can't seem to trigger the settings screen, boot into windows (one last time).  Select restart and hold down the shift key when you click the button.  When it reboots, you will be presented with options.. one of them will be to access the UEFI menus.

***This might differ a little bit in your UEFI settings.. but it will be similar.***  Most modern UEFI settings (aka BIOS) have this option hidden in there *somewhere*.  They hide it (I think) because it is a devastating mistake to make for someone goofing around.

If you simply want to leave an empty drive behind ***and not use the UEFI utility***, you can boot from something else..

- [Linux Live Disk](https://www.linuxliveusb.com/)
- [Hiren's Boot PE](https://www.hirensbootcd.org/)
- Windows PE (built into windows media)
- many many other tools..

Each of these options provide utilities to actually erase the drive (to include secure erase).

The secret is that you can't erase the drive while you are using it.  You will need to boot to something else to get the job done.

***Because reasons*** .. nah.. I doubt it.. no conspiracy here.. :)
Very few people would want to do that because a computer without an operating system is worthless and that Dell will always have a licensed copy of windows associated with it.  If (for instance), you wanted Linux.. you would wipe the windows drive at the same time you were installing the new operating system.

Answer (score 1):

I've never seen a "wipe" option in bios/uefi, but I haven't had much to do with uefi so it could be new.

Windows 8(?)+, certainly 10, requires secureboot, which, for the sake of ease, you will need to disable to install another OS. There are probably a few other bios tweaks you will want to make, specific to your target OS.
Dell may provide a "clean" bios/uefi you can flash from a bootable dvd/usb.
Once you can boot another OS/media, then hiren, active@, or a linux live distro has the tools to wipe the harddrive.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).